# Strange output from dereferencing pointers into a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I was writing a program in C++ where I need to have a 2d grid of pointers which point to objects which are stored in a vector.  I tested out some part of the program and saw strange results in the output.

I changed the objects to integers and removed everything non-essential to cut it down to the code snippet below, but I still get a weird output.

```cpp
vector<vector<int*>> lattice(10, vector<int*>(10));//grid of pointers

vector<int> relevant;//vector carrying actual values onto which pointers will point

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    int new_integer = i;
    relevant.push_back(new_integer);//insert integer into vector
    lattice[0][i] = &relevant[i];//let pointer point onto this value
}

//OUTPUT
for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
    cout<<*lattice[0][j]<<" ";
    cout<<relevant[j]<<endl;
}
```

I get strange outputs like this:

```
19349144 0
19374040 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

Also, my output changes from run to run and depending on how big/small I make my grid.

I would expect all the values on the left and right to be equal, I guess there is something fundamental about pointers I haven't understood, so sorry if this is a very basic question.

Can someone please explain why I get strange outputs for some values of the grid?

Comment: Undefined behavior. The vector can reallocate internal memory, you are pointing to, between `push_back`s.

Comment: Sorry can you explain it in a bit more detail, I don't understand.

Comment: What happens if you try `cout<<*(lattice[0][j])<<" ";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `std::vector` is inserted into, if its new `size()` will exceed its current `capacity()`, the vector has to reallocate its internal array to make room, which will invalidate any existing iterators and pointers to the old memory.

In your example, you can avoid that by `reserve()`'ing the `capacity()` ahead of time, eg:

```cpp
vector<vector<int*>> lattice(10, vector<int*>(10));//grid of pointers

vector<int> relevant;//vector carrying actual values onto which pointers will point

//ADD THIS!
relevant.reserve(10);//pre-allocate the capacity

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    int new_integer = i;
    relevant.push_back(new_integer);//insert integer into vector
    lattice[0][i] = &relevant[i];//let pointer point onto this value
}

//OUTPUT
for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
    cout<<*lattice[0][j]<<" ";
    cout<<relevant[j]<<endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can pre-allocate the `size()` and then use `operator[]` instead of `push_back()`, eg:

```cpp
vector<vector<int*>> lattice(10, vector<int*>(10));//grid of pointers

vector<int> relevant(10);//vector carrying actual values onto which pointers will point

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    int new_integer = i;
    relevant[i] = new_integer;//insert integer into vector
    lattice[0][i] = &relevant[i];//let pointer point onto this value
}

//OUTPUT
for(int j = 0; j<10; j++){
    cout<<*lattice[0][j]<<" ";
    cout<<relevant[j]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You're giving OP poor advise by suggesting they keep pointers into a vector, relying on the lucky break of a `reserve()` preventing pointer invalidations initially. The vector might be changed later on, or elsewhere in the code, and the pointers will again be invalid. Keeping pointers into a vector is generally a wrong thing to do; with the exception being scopes where the vector is `const`. @DeltaChief: FYI.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to have a 2d grid of pointers which point to objects which are stored in a vector

That's impossible. Or rather, that's a guarantee for dereferencing invalid addresses. Why?

At any given time, an [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has enough space allocated for some limited number of elements. If you keep adding elements to it, it will eventually max out its storage. At some insertion, it will decide allocate a new stretch of memory to use for storing its data; move (or copy) existing data to the new storage area; free the old storage area; and then be able to add more elements.

When this happens, all existing pointers into objects in the vector become *invalid*. The memory they point to may continue to hold the previous values, but may also be used to store other data - there are no guarantees on that! In fact, dereferencing invalid pointers officially results in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

... and I do see that what I've described is exactly what you're doing with your code. Your older pointers become invalid.

Instead, consider keeping *indices* into the vector rather than pointers. Indices don't get invalidated by adding elements to the vector, and you can keep using them.

---

<sub>PS - I see you're using a vector-of-vectors. That's technically valid, but it is often unadvisable. Consider using a matrix class (e.g. from the Eigen library) or allocating a certain amount of memory using [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), then using it to initialize a [`gsl::multi_span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).</sub>

Comment: OP's approach could work if they never change the size of the vector. Though I wouldn't recomment that either.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: "Never" is a very relative state of affairs in programming. Tomorrow someone will introduce another addition and get surprising errors. So, you're right, but you're more right in not recommending doing that.

Comment: The code should `reserve()` the vector elements before entering the `push_back()` loop. That would avoid the reallocation issue and not invalidate the pointers

Comment: About the "Why" I want to do this: I am writing a very big simulation of cells growing on a long grid (or rather a long corridor). I always only need to "remember a certain ammount of cells at the front of my growing interface, while I can "forget" cells left behind which have no relation anymore to the cells at the front. Because of this I wanted to use a grid of pointers which so to say wanders along with my growing front. I need this grid because I need some spatial structure for implementing the growing algorithm.

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It would still put the program in a very brittle position.

Comment: @DeltaChief: I can't presume to give you a decent recommendation for what seems to be a rather involved computational task. Please consider consulting people with more software and data structure design experience, who can seriously look into your challenge.

Answer (score 1):

`relevant.push_back` invalidates all pointers/references/iterators to its elements (if the new size exceeds its current capacity).

Therefore you are dereferencing potentially invalid pointers when you do

```
*lattice[0][j]
```

later.

You can use a container that doesn't invalidate on insertion at the end, such as [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) or [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), instead of `std::vector`, for `relevant`.

(Or you can reserve a sufficient capacity with a call to [`.reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) first, so that the size on the `.push_back` operations will never exceed the capacity and will therefore never invalidate pointers, but that carries the risk of easily accidentally ignoring this requirement on later code changes, again causing UB.)