# Grid of pointers to keep spatial structure over changing amount of objects C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

TL:DR
I want to keep track of the spatial structure of some objects via a 2d vector of pointers pointing onto the objects. The objects themselves are in a 1d vector. I was told this is not the way to do things and I am searching for a better approach.

I want to write a simulation on spatial cell growth in C++. The cells should be placed onto some kind of 2d grid because I need a spatial structure between them to implement the growing algorithm. The simulation starts from a line of cells in a "corridor" of set width, but not yet known length. For implementing the growing algorithm which repeatedly places new cells adjacent to some old cell onto the grid, I need a spatial structure between the cells (hence the usage of a 2d grid). This growth process will go on for an extremely long time until some condition is met. Sometimes it will end quickly but sometimes the needed "length" of my corridor will exceed the memory capacity of my computer. Luckily I only need to remember certain cells in the back of my corridor. Some cells whose ancestry line looses connection to the growing front of the cell colony can be "forgotten". Also, I only need this 2d spatial structure for some small grid "wandering along" the front of my cells colony, since further along in the back everything will be filled already and therefore the spatial structure there is not important anymore.

I therefore want to have some data structure which keeps track of my "important" cells, which doesn't have to be spatially structured, and then some additional small grid structure which wanders along with the front of my colony and can point to the cells currently at the front of my growing interface.

My initial idea was to have a 2d grid of pointers which point to a large vector. The vector would keep track of all the important cells, i.e. in every new cell object would be added to the vector and once it becomes unimportant I would delete it from the vector. At the same time the grid of pointers which points at the elements of the vector would keep track of my spatial structure at the front and the pointers would be updated as soon as my cells grow out of my pointer grid, i.e. then I would move my grid along with the front.

I was told in a different question ([Strange output from dereferencing pointers into a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792327/strange-output-from-dereferencing-pointers-into-a-vector)) I had, that it is not good to have pointers to a vector. I don't see how else I could do it though. Maybe someone has an idea on how to handle this. Thank you!

Comment: Why you can't store indices inside your vector instead of pointers? Pointers get invalidated when host vector got resized, indices wouldn't.

Comment: @MinorThreat but if I delete elements from my vector the indices would also shift, right? And I need to delete elements from the vector since otherwise it will get too large again.

Comment: Have you tried simpler approach with a single array sorted by composite key [x, y] ? If you have to constantly lookup for  adjacent cells by y, you could make another array {[y,  x] index_in_first _array} sorted by  [y, x].

Answer (score 1):

As of what I understand from your question, and I am sure I do not understand it fully, I think what you want is to simulate some kind of cells growing in a 2-D grid.

Assuming your cell is some kind of an object, Store your **cells** directly into a 2-D array and have a list that stores the indices of the important cells.

As an implementation, let: -

```
class Cell{
    ...    //data members

    bool enabled;    //Just for representing empty/available spaces in 2-D grid. If it is set to true, then there is a cell in the specific unit of the grid.
    Cell(){
        enabled = false;
    }

    ...    //other cell data
}
```

be your class that is used to make individual cell objects; then: -

```
std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> grid(m, vector<Cell>(n));
```

would represent your 2-D grid of size m*n.

Now, due to the default constructor, all the cells inside `grid` would have `enabled = false`. This is good because it can work as empty spaces for your cells to grow.

Next, have a list that stores your 'important' cell's indices: -

```
struct Index{
    int x, y;
    Index(int x_, int y_){
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
    }
}
std::list<Index> importantCells;
```

**Note**: I am using list here because I assume you don't need random access.

Initially, *put* some 'important' cells into your grid, for example at (0, 0) of your grid: -

```
grid[0][0] = Cell(...) //Assuming you have some parameterized constructor for that...
```

and now, store the index `0,0` in your `importantCells` list: -

```
importantCells.emplace_back(0, 0);    //or use push_back() if you wish
```

Now, traverse `importantCells` list, read the positions of 'important' cells and update them in your 2-D `grid`. This will lead to generation of new 'important' cells and possibly removing the current 'important' cell(because it might not have more room to grow). For the newly generated cells, add them to the list using `emplace_front`, and if the current cell becomes unimportant, remove it from the list...

You can also use vector if you want random access, but lists seems better for your scenario.